# Test environment - errors with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, paperclip

I am beginning to write tests for an application and I'm having trouble getting the test environment to work.
My system has **Paperclip** for file uploads and it's tripping up at any attempt to start the server or even to initialize a new company record! An example:

```
# Company.rb line 3
has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles => {:medium => "200x300>", :thumb => "100x150>" },
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{::Rails.root.to_s}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => "/photos/:style/:id/:basename.:extension"

# console
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :001 > Company.new
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]=
from /Users/san/Documents/san/app/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:232:in 'has_attached_file'
from /Users/san/Documents/san/app/app/models/company.rb:3:in '<class:company>'
from /Users/san/Documents/san/app/app/models/company.rb:1:in '<top (required)>'
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in 'load'
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in 'block in load_file'
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in 'new_constants_in'
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:453:in 'load_file'
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:340:in 'require_or_load'
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:491:in 'load_missing_constant'
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in 'block in const_missing'
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in 'each'
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in 'const_missing'
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:206:in 'const_missing_from_s3_library'
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in 'const_missing'
from (irb):1
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in 'start'
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in 'start'
from /Users/san/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in '<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in 'require'
```

Do you know what's causing this conflict and how I can fix it?

---

I read through the Paperclip docs and I discovered the need to add:

```
require 'paperclip/matchers'
Spec::Runner.configure do |config|
  config.include Paperclip::Shoulda::Matchers
end
```

to `spec_helper.rb`. Still getting the same error!

Comment: What is on line 10 of the company model?

Comment: The `has_attached_file :photo` line.

Comment: @RyanBigg - I'm doing some more digging and realizing it's broader than Rspec. When I run something as simple as `Employee.new` in my test console I'm getting the same error (`trying to evaluate nil.[]=` and pointing at Employee's first attachment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the error was fixed by downgrading Paperclip to 2.3.6, which is what I was using up until a week ago. Hopefully this is helpful to anyone experiencing this error in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I reckon what that is is the `s3.yml` doesn't contain a key for your current Rails environment, probably `test`? Add one. That should fix it!

Comment: I checked the S3 bucket names, the access_key and the secret_access_key, and everything seems to check out. Could it be something else?